# Subsites in scaffold website in Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

I would like to know if there is a canonical way to create websites in the default Yesod scaffolded website. Indeed, I thinks it's very important to be able to have a modular code, and it seems that subsite is the classical way to do so.

In the same idea, is there a place where all yesod "extentions"/"subsites" could be find (for example to easily include a blog, a forum...) ?

Thank you,

TobiasBora.